# TypeScript cannot find js module in same folder

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am struggling to load a .js module which is in the same folder as my .ts file. I have 4 file in the same folder:

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./foo.d.ts" />

import foo = require('./foo.js');
```

**node.d.ts**

Copied from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

**foo.d.ts**

```
declare module "foo" {
    export function hello(): void;
}
```

**foo.js**

```
module.exports = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
};
```

When I run `tsc index.ts --module commonjs`, I get the following error:

```
index.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './foo.js'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since node.js will resolve `foo` via relative path rather than looking for it in the `node_modules` directory like it would with a module you'd installed via npm, you need to drop `declare module "foo"` in `foo.d.ts`. Also, in `index.ts`, drop the `.js` extension when calling `require`.

**foo.d.ts**

```
export function hello(): void;
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./foo.d.ts" />

import foo = require('./foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use require without relative path

```
var foo = require('foo');
```

See related [article](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2712) for details.